# How does Haskell evaluate this primes function?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, weak-head-normal-form

I find it rather difficult to understand how Haskell will evaluate this `primes` function. Is the `primes` function get evaluated over and over, or the `primes` in the `primeFactors` function will point back to the first `primes`?

```
primes = 2 : filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) [3,5..]

primeFactors n = factor n primes
  where
    factor n (p:ps)
        | p * p > n        = [n]
        | n `mod` p == 0   = p : factor (n `div` p) (p:ps)
        | otherwise        = factor n ps

main :: IO ()
main = print $ length . take 100000 $ primes
```

Comment: `primes` isn't a function at all; it's just a list.

Comment: Thank you. So under the hood, every time the primeFactors is called the `primes`  now is different from the last time we call primeFactors. Is this `partially evaluating`?

Comment: @dandoh `primes` never changes, like all values in Haskell. `primes` is just self-referential – it's like the infinite list `x = 1 : x`, which is an infinite list of `1`s.

Comment: Off topic, but checking if a non-empty list has exactly one element can be done with `null . tail` instead of `(== 1) . length`.  This way `primeFactors` will stop computing factors once it finds a second factor instead of computing all of them.  Note that this will not work for empty lists (which is not the case here).

Comment: Such definitions are known as [constant applicative forms](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form)

Answer (score 6):

`primes` is just a list. Its first element is 2, and the rest of the elements are taken from the list of odd integers filtered by (in part) the function `primeFactors`.

`primeFactors`, though, uses `primes`. Isn't this circular?

Not quite. Because Haskell is lazy, `primeFactors` doesn't need all the values in `primes` at once, just the ones that are less than or equal to the square root of its argument (`p:ps` matches against `primes`, but we only need `ps` if `p*p <= n`), and those primes were all found by previous calls to `primeFactors`.

As an example, trace the first few calls to `primeFactors`. For brevity, let `b = (==1) . length . primeFactors`.

```
primeFactors 3 == factor 3 primes
               -- only unpack as much of primes as we need for the next step
               == factor 3 (2:filter b [3,5..])
               -- because 2*2 > 3, that's only one level
               == [3]
```

And so, since `b [3]` is true, we know that 3 is the next element of `primes`. That is, `primes = 2:3:filter b [5,7..]`

```
primeFactors 5 == factor 5 primes
               == factor 5 (2:3:filter b [3,5..])
               -- 2*2 > 5 is false, as is 5 `mod` 2 == 0, so
               == factor 5 (3:filter b [3,5..])
               -- 3*3 > 5, so
               == [5]
```

And `b [5]` is true, so `5` is the next element of `primes`.

```
primeFactors 7 == factor 7 primes
               == factor 7 (2:3:5:filter b [3,5..])
               == factor 7 (3:5:filter b [3,5..])
               -- 3*3 > 7
               == [7]
```

And `b [7]` is true, so `7` is the next element of `primes`. (Seems like everything gets added to `primes`, doesn't? One more call to `primeFactors` will show that isn't the case)

```
primeFactors 9 == factor 9 primes
               == factor 9 (2:3:5:7:filter b [3,5..])
               -- 2*2 > 9 and 9 `mod` 2 == 0 are false
               == factor 9 (3:5:7:filter b [3,5..])
               -- 3*3 > 9 is false, but 9 `mod` 3 == 0 is true, so
               == 3 : factor (9 `div` 3) (3:5:7:filter b [3,5..])
               == 3 : factor 3 (3:5:7:filter b [3,5..])
               -- 3*3 > 3 is false, but 3 `mod` 3 == 0, so
               == 3 : [3] == [3,3]
```

But since `b [3,3]` is false, `9` is *not* an element of `primes`. So now we have

```
 primes = 2:3:5:7:filter b [3,5..])
```

It's a long and tedious process to trace this, but you should get the feeling that `primes` always stays "ahead" of `primeFactors`; the elements of `primes` that `primeFactors` needs have always been determined by earlier calls to `primeFactors`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So internally speaking, `primes` always points to the same block of memory, and it will be evaluated gradually?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: A simpler example of the same concept is the infinite list of ones, `ones = 1:ones`.  `head ones == 1`, and `tail ones = ones`. What's `head (tail ones)`? Well, it's `head (tail (1:ones)) == head ones == head (1:ones) == 1` (always replacing the definition of `ones` with `1:ones` only when absolutely necessary).

Answer (score 3):

> how Haskell will evaluate this primes function?

As your code shown in question, it print out first 100000 prime numbers, so how `primes` to work?

Firstly, for generating the first prime number, it is simple, just first element of the list:

```
2 : filter ((==1) ...
```

that is `2`, and for the next one, we need to apply `primeFactors` function as

```
primeFactors 3 = factor 3 primes
```

and now may confuse someone who new to Haskell, how to evaluate the `primes` in above expression? the answer is that, it is just a list with elements as `[2,...]`, thanks to lazy evaluation, now, we don't need to evaluate all the prime numbers of list generated by `primes` function. we just need to evaluate **next one** and look and see what happen. So, we get `2`, and the above expression become:

```
 primeFactors 3 = factor 3 [2,..]
```

and

```
factor 3 (2:ps) | 2 * 2 > 3 = [3]
```

So, `primeFactors 3` retrun `[3]`

and, so

```
2: filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) 3 = [2,3]
```

we now successfully generate 2 prime numbers, but we need 100000, and how about next? Obviously, we apply `5` to below expression:

```
2: filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) 5
```

repeats the procedure as above:

```
primeFactors 5 = factor 5 [2,3,..]
```

and this time we have 2 elements in the list:

```
factor 5 [2,3..]
```

and

```
factor 5 [2,3..] | otherwise = factor 5 [3,...]
```

and

```
factor 5 [3,...] | 3 * 3 > 5 = [5]
```

and repeat again and again till to generate 100000 prime numbers, and again, due to lazy evaluation, we don't need 100001 prime number, so the computation stop and print out the result.